# Its posible to restruct tab behavior in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, tabs, python-decorators

I'm not even sure about how to describe my question. So if you don't understand, I probably don't either. so I will appreciate any complaint

I'm writing a tedious and large piece of code. I reach a point were i could be so benefited if I can rewrite the behavior of the tab indentation.
I would like that when I tab a piece of code, that code is executed between other lines of code, similar to what can be achieved with a decorator

```py
#Change this
ini_fun()
tedious_code()
tedious_code()
ini_fun()
tedious_code()
end_fun()
tedious_code()
end_fun()

#To this
''' Start different behavior '''
    tedious_code()
    tedious_code()
        tedious_code()
    tedious_code()
```

So... Is there any way to achieve this?

I don't want to mess with the compiler.

Comment: That sounds like you should write a context manager and use `with` statements, not try to completely overhaul the fundamentals of Python syntax.

Comment: thanks. I didn't even know where to start, that's why I went so deep. I'll start there and I'll probably come back to complain because it didn't come out